# IBM Cognos analytics using the totals of one row in a singleton

Tags: analytics, cognos

I made a table with client_names, amount and a ranking.
in this table I filtered so I only see the top 10 clients.

Underneath the amount row I made a total. now I want to use this total for only the top 10 clients to make a singleton where I can eventually make a calculation which shows the percentage of the actual total amount.

can someone help me how to do this cause everytime I try to use a CASE WHEN or IF THEN ELSE construction it doesn't work like the following:

```
CASE WHEN [ranking] <= 10
THEN [amount]
END
```

or

```
CASE [client_name] WHEN [ranking] <= 10
THEN [amount]
END
```

every time I do something like this it just shows me the actual total amount and not for the top 10 clients.

I hope someone can help me with this problem ;) thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eventually this worked for me:
rank (IF([Cliënt] <> null) THEN([amount]) ELSE (0) )

this got me the top 10 clients and worked like a charm. thanks everyone for the help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
TOTAL(
 CASE 
 WHEN [ranking] <= 10 
 THEN [amount] 
 ELSE 0 
 END
 for report
)
```

Set the data item's Aggregate Function property to 'Calculated' because you are supplying your own aggregate expression.

Comment: Hey Johnsonium,

thanks for the answer while this gave me a number it is not the correct number; cause I cant explicitly say which clients it is about i can say the following. this is an example im working with:

CLIENT// AMOUNT// RANK
1// 174.884,53// 1
2// 158.020,91// 2
3// 137.304,81// 3
4// 126.278,16// 4
5// 119.342,68// 5
6// 110.116,51// 6
7// 91.903,28  // 7
8// 84.087,52  // 8
9// 81.940,46  // 9
10// 75.638,71 // 10
TOTAL// 1.159.517,57

In the singleton with your code i get the number 191.513,79 . ofcourse I want the number that is after total.

Comment: OK. I amended the expression, adding 'for report' to the total function. This calculates the number for the entire report rather than on each line.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, I will definatly try that thuesday and come back to you when I have :)